# Top methods that are Scalability Bottlenecks

Tags: c#, wcf

I am using SOA Architecture for project using Microsoft Technologies .NET 3.5 Platform. Can you give me steps/tools/guidelines/knowledge on the shortest and fast route to find the methods that cause the major Hardware bottlenecks like CPU time, memory usage. Also suggest what are the ways to improve thoroughput, scalability with response time.

Regards/Anand

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any "short and fast route" to find any kind of bottle neck. So this is how I would approach the problem:

We usually generate logs for general time measures. You could inject a WCF behaviour which logs duration of each server method call. You could produce statistics from that. Consider duration of a method call and also number of calls to the same method (only optimize frequent method calls).

Memory is more complicated. You need to call a method separately to measure memory of a single method. Mostly it depends on existing data. There are tools to hunt memory leaks, if you intent to do this.

I found most unnecessary performance problems by observing database activity (eg. using Profiler for Sql Server).